# How can I solve the problems mentioned below?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and nothing comes to my mind on how can I find a solution for these **three problems**...

1. Less than 15% of the characters on a sentence should be numbers.
2. Max. 9 vowels on a sentence.
3. Max. 12 words on a sentence.

**The ones that I did right (If I'm not mistaken somewhere):**

1. The sentence should start with "An".
2. The sentence should contain the word "apple".
3. The last character of the sentence should be number.

**The code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise5 {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner scan=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Write a sentence:");
        String sent=scan.nextLine();
        
        if (sent.startsWith("An") && sent.contains("apple") && 
                sent.charAt(sent.length()-1)>='0' && sent.charAt(sent.length()-1)<='9'){
            System.out.println("The sentence is correct.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Wrong.");
        } 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer: step back and figure how you would do that manually. Percentage implies that you understand *quantities*. Meaning: you have to **count** things. Like: walk over the characters within your `sent` string and for each character, test whether it is a number or a letter. When it is a letter, check if it is a vowel or not. So, use a search and look for "iterate chars in a java string" for example.

Comment: Max. 9 vowels on a sentence. Max. 12 words on a sentence.

If the above requirement is not met then did u consider the sentence as invalid?

Comment: Why can't you identify which characters are vowels?  If you can, why can't you count them?  Why can't you identify words?  If you can, why can't you count them?  You already know how to identify digits; why can't you count them?

Comment: Yes @SumitSingh, if the requirements aren't met, the sentence is invalid.

Comment: I will post the answer soon

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Chain of Responsibility pattern` and check all you need.

```java
public abstract class Handler {
    private Handler next;

    public abstract boolean check(final String str);

    protected boolean checkNext(final String str) {
        if (next == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return next.check(str);
    }
    
    public Handler linkWith(Handler next) {
        this.next = next;
        return next;
    }
}

public class VowelsHandler extends Handler {
    private final static int NUM_OF_VOWELS = 9;
    private final static List<Character> vowels = Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');

    @Override
    public boolean check(String str) {
        final boolean result = str.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).filter(vowels::contains).count() <= NUM_OF_VOWELS;

        return result && checkNext(str);
    }
}

public class WordsHandler extends Handler {
    private final static int NUM_OF_WORDS_IN_SENTENCE = 12;
    @Override
    public boolean check(String str) {
        String[] arr = str.split("\\b");
        final boolean result = arr.length <= NUM_OF_WORDS_IN_SENTENCE;

        return result && checkNext(str);
    }
}

public class Main {
    private Handler handler;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        Handler handler = new VowelsHandler();
        handler.linkWith(new WordsHandler());
        boolean result = handler.check("a b c d e f g h i j k l m");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

You need only create a new implementation of a `Handler` abstract class and add it to the chain.

```java
handler.linkWith(new PercentHandler());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing this method

```
private static String sentenceValidity(String str) {
        
        String[] split = str.split(" ");
        
        int v_count = 0, chr_count = 0, len = str.length(), split_length = split.length;
        
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        
        if(split_length < 12) {
            
            for(int ndx = 0 ; ndx < len ; ++ ndx) {
                
                char c = str.charAt(ndx);
                
                if(!Character.isDigit(c)) {
                    
                    chr_count++;

                    if(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' )  v_count++;
            
                }               
                
                if(v_count > 9) 
                    return "Invalid string more than 9 vowles";
                
                if(((float)chr_count/len)*100 > 15)
                    return "Invalid string more than 15% charachters";                      
            }
            
        }else {
            return "Invalid string more than 12 words";
        }
        
        return "Valid String";      
        
    }
```